# Building Boost 1.60 with Windows SDK 10.0.10586.0

Tags: c++, windows, boost

I was able to build boost when using the Windows SDK 10.0.10240, but as a company we've decided to standardize on using the latest SDK which is 10.0.10586.0. I think Visual Studio Update 2 installs (or at least can install) that.

When I try to build boost with the new SDK I get errors such as:

```
libs\thread\src\win32\tss_pe.cpp(81): fatal warning C1083: Cannot open include file: 'windows.h': No such file or directory
```

I've noticed that during the build, a batch file from my temp folder runs which looks like this:

C:\Users\scottl\AppData\Local\Temp\b2_msvc_14.0_vcvarsall_x86.cmd

```
SET INCLUDE=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\winrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\winrt;
SET LIB=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\lib\um\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10240.0\um\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\lib\um\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10240.0\um\x86;
SET LIBPATH=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References;\Microsoft.VCLibs\14.0\References\CommonConfiguration\neutral;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References;\Microsoft.VCLibs\14.0\References\CommonConfiguration\neutral;
SET Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow;C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\VCPackages;C:\Program Files (x86)\HTML Help Workshop;C:\Program Files (x86)\HTML Help Workshop;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow;C:\Users\scottl\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\VCPackages;C:\Program Files (x86)\HTML Help Workshop;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\;C:\Program Files (x86)\BullseyeCoverage\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files (x86)\RSA SecurID Token Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;"C:\Users\scottl\OneDrive\Scripts";C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2015 Power Tools\;C:\Windows\idmu\common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\
```

There are lots of references to the old SDK which I don't have. I've searched the boost source and can't see the SDK version mentioned, so I'm not sure where it is finding it from.

How do I configure boost to use the latest SDK?

Comment: Somebody else seems to have the same problem: http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2015/12/85501.php

Comment: Somebody else also has e a problem with `Visual Studio Update 2` compiling `boost`, see: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/12115 ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boost Build creates that batch file to cache the rather slow MSVC setup required when running individual toolset commands. You can either delete that file, which should then get recreated. Or you can use the "--reconfigure" b2 option, which **should** also regenerate that file.

Comment: The --reconfigure option doesn't appear to be supported. To my build script I added something like "del %temp%\b2_*.cmd" to the top to prevent getting this again.